# Android AsyncTask and Multi-Part HTTP Requests

Tags: android, json, http, android-asynctask

I am newer to Android and apologize for sounding so. The code would add little value so in short, I have an AsyncTask already that returns JSON, whereby I must then take a certain value from each array from that JSON result and input it into a Google maps API http request to find out the users distance from a certain location.

Calculating distance is no problem, but what is the best practice for this apparent multi-level requirement, ie. http request -> JSON parse -> http request -> JSON parse -> display to user, without using a string of multiple separate AsyncTasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all the parsing and requests you need to inside `doWork` of a single AsyncTask. You don't really need a special pattern for this unless you want to start doing multiple Google Maps API requests in parallel.

Comment: Is there a source/documentation for the doWork method?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say doInBackground, I will update the answer,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ion lib` from Kaush. It will make Async Http request and return you JSON Object. You can also use `GSON` with this library.

You can get this library from [HERE](https://github.com/koush/ion)